# Workspaces indicator not working in Ubuntu 19.04

Tags: 19.04, workspaces, gnome-shell-extension, extension

Workspaces indicator (https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/21/workspace-indicator/) does not work for me in Ubuntu 19.04, which is weird cause it is one of the default extensions, and everyone at extensions.gnome.org claims it works.

What can I do to fix this? Is it possible? Thanks!

Comment: There are a few folks at the link you indicate, that say it's not working for them with 19.04 and the recent GNOME Shells. It's not one of the default extensions. If you disable your other extensions, and restart GNOME Shell, does it work then?

Comment: If you boot from a LiveUSB of 19.04 and set up the Workspaces Indicator, does it work while you are booted from the LiveUSB? Please click [edit] and advise; please do not use Add Comment, but instead use [edit].

Comment: I have workspaces in unity on 19 but only 4 and not the 10 I have configured in unity tweak tool / compiz settings.